# how to set UIPickerView value selection when it dismissed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How to set UIPickerView Selection value, when it is dismissed and reopen UIPicker selected Value.

Example:  i have picker which do have component Element 1m,2m,3m,4m,5m,  and i selected 3m, and then the value is set when i do resign or remove or dismissed the picker and open the same picker view it need to display the selected the value which is 3m.

@ All

i try my best if you have any idea let me know

I am not able to answer so i am updating my question

again but its not working for me any one help me out.

```
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        //On Selecting the component row
        if (component == 0) {

        } else if (component == 1) {
            [quantityPickerDelegate didChangeLabelText:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] PriceValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f $",priceValue * ([[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] floatValue]/20)]];
            [pickerView reloadComponent:component]; //This will cause your viewForComp to hit
            pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.selectedRow = [quantityPickerView selectedRowInComponent:component];
    }

This my delegate method.

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [quantityPickerView selectRow:self.selectedRow inComponent:1 animated:YES];

}
```

this is what i did its selecting only zero.

Comment: Do i need to use NSUserDefault for this kind of situation

Answer (score 1):

try this method of UIPIckerView

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the selected row no in any variable when you want to dismiss your picker as:

int selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component];

And call this method when you want to reopen your picker:

```
[pickerView selectRow:selectedRow inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:YES];
```

//where (NSInteger)component is your component no as 0, 1 etc.....

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

 NSLog(@"selected Row %d",selectedRow);
// [quantityPickerView selectRow:selectedRow inComponent:1 animated:YES];
 [quantityPickerView selectRow:[quantityPickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] inComponent:1 animated:YES];
}  This is what i am doing it's not working.  its setting zero always.

Comment: quantityPickerView is an UIPickerView

Comment: Print  "[quantityPickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]" value by NSLog and check the "[quantityPickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]" value is same as u required.

Comment: No its not same its 0 i  am getting.

Comment: You have to create a global variable int selectedRow and set the value of selectedRow where you select any row in Picker and call the method with this selected row.

Comment: i did that. Global variable int selectedRow and fetching data from didselected and assigning it into viewwillappears.  its not working.

Comment: then why are you using [quantityPickerView selectRow:[quantityPickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] inComponent:1 animated:YES]; simply use:[quantityPickerView selectRow:seletedRow inComponent:1 animated:YES];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4329/discussion-between-user891268-and-iphonedv)